# Unable to prove an identity regarding a circle within a triangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

I was asked,

The triangle ABC has for equal parts AB and AC. The midpoint of BC is M, and AM = r. A circular arc with centre A and radius r is drawn and meets the sides AB and AC  at the points L and N respectively. Angle CAM = X radians. Given that the area of the sector ALMN is $\frac{1}{4}$ of the triangle ABC, show that $X = \frac{1}{4} \tan X$.

What I did,

$\frac{1}{2} r^2 2X = \frac{1}{4} 2r^2 \tan X$.

From there I conclude $X = \frac{1}{2} \tan X$.

Comment: This isn't a question. Would you like to have the proof peer reviewed?

Comment: the question seems to be that he is getting $1/2 \cdots$ instead that the given answer $1/4 \cdots$

Comment: What I meant I reached X = 1/2 tanX while I was supposed to show it equal to X = 1/4 tanX.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding! I thought you said that $X = \frac{1}{4} \tan X$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area of $\triangle BAC$ is $2 \cdot 1/2\cdot r \cdot r \tan X$. Area of the sector $ALMN$ is $(2X)/(2\pi)(\pi r^2)= Xr^2$ . Therefore $Xr^2 =1/4 r^2 \tan X$

Comment: Is the area of sector not 1/2 r^2 2X, could you please explain the statement for ALMN you advanced. Thank you.

Comment: @Gavish: yes you can calculate the sector area also like that ($1/2 \cdot (L=r\cdot 2X) \cdot r). I went instead through the ratio angle ($2X) to $360^circ$ times the whole circle area: the result is of course the same : $Xr^2$. In your formula the mistake is in the triangle area: half triangle is rect with cathetus $r$ and angle $X$, so $1/2 \cdot r \cdot r \cdot tanX$) , then times $2$ gives $r^2 \cdot tanX$. Then you have to take $1/4$ ...

Comment: Alright thank you very much !